# Unix terminal command for shutting down all running applications?

Tags: macos, unix

Wondering if anyone knew of a unix terminal command for shutting down all running applications. Any and all help is welcome. Cheers ~

Comment: Related: [How to kill all processes in Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/161531/how-to-kill-all-processes-in-linux)

Comment: This may help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42688/gnome-how-to-close-all-applications

Comment: Do you want to kill **all** processes? The only one you cannot kill is the first one, you need to shutdown the system for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of below command:

```
shutdown -r now
reboot
init 6
killall5
```